# Angular 14 - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reduce') at Compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync

Tags: angular

I upgraded Angular from version 7 to version 14.
When I used the following code in Angular 14 to try to load a custom plugin module

```
return SystemJS.import(url).then((module) => {
            return this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(module[`${moduleInfo.moduleName}`]).then(compiled => {
                return compiled;
            });
        });
```

It throws below error
[image]

When using the same above code it works fine in Angular 7